# How can we embed the external page of different site on a page of our wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

Actual Scenario - We have a wp multisite. I need to show the content of a parent site's page on a sub site's page. 
Please let me know if you need any clarification about the problem.

I tried some of the methods which are - 
1) use switch_to_blog method but the problem with this is - I am using page builder widget on my main site's page and when this method fetch the content on sub site, it did not show the content with correct layout.

2) use iframe - I could not find any way to write the css inside the iframe attributes.

Here i am adding my way how od i use iframe.

```
<iframe class="my_irame" src="http://externalpage.com"></iframe>
```

This output me -

```
<object id="myframe" width="100%" height="600px" myfunction()"="" style="overflow:auto;> </object>
<html>
<body>
<div id="header">some text</div>
<div class="container>some text</div>
</body>
/html>
```

My concern is to hide the div inside iframe having id **header**.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly. when using iframes you want to change the style of the page inside the iframe?

Comment: Yes, Correct. This could also be help me as a solution there.

Comment: I also added my way to use iframe and also the problem for which i need the solution.

Comment: If that is the case and you can edit both sites then I can give you a hack to get the info from the parent site and style it differently for only the iframe. I'll post the hack as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the styles for only the contents within an iframe from the parent site I would suggest doing the following.

Create the iframe on the page you want to pull content into like so:

```
<iframe class="my_irame" src="http://externalpage.com/folder/pagename?iframe=show"></iframe>
```

In the above iframe we're sending a get request to the page that loads the content inside the iframe.

Then on the site pulling into the iframe you create a new stylesheet below your other styles just before the closing `</head>` tag with a PHP if statement.

```
<?php if($_GET['iframe']=='active'){ ?>
        <link href="styleSheetToOverWriteAllOtherStyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <?php } ?>
```

The above stylesheet will only be used where the `?iframe=active` is being used in the URL or src. And thus only on your iframe and you can then in this stylesheet hide the header of the parent site without it affecting the parent sites styles. You can actually then override all styles from the parent site for the iframe.

If there are going to be links within the iframe then just let me know as that will make it a bit more complex. Especially if they reload the iframe.